# Looped DIV not keeping table structure from previous

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a table to which contains alot of ordering details, however, when i want to add a product, from the admin page, even though all of the original table structure works fine, once the jQuery echoes an extra DIV to give me more table, can anyone reccomend a way in jquery to just add a few rows to an existing table for example...

```
<?php echo('
<tr>
        <th colspan="2"><label>Item '.$mCount.'</label></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="1"><label for="itemDetailvar1'.$mCount.'">Track var1:</label></td> 
    <td colspan="1"><input type="text" size="25" name="itemDetails['.$mCount.'][var1]" value="" id="itemDetailvar1'.$mCount.'" " /></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <th colspan="2"><div id="itemPlacer"></div><a href="#" onclick="addNewItem(); return false;">Add Another Music Item</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
');
$mCount++;
?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var currCount = <?php echo($mCount); ?>;

            function addNewItem(){
jQuery("#itemPlacer").append('<tr><th colspan="2"><label>Track '+currCount+'</label></th></tr><tr><td colspan="1"><label for="itemDetailvar1'+currCount+'">Track var1:</label></td></tr>');             
                currCount++;
                return false;
            }
        </script>
```

i just need to know a way to add a few basic table functions with jQuery so if someone can show me a way to have a button that says
"Add Item" and then on click, it adds a few table rows, that would be perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing "itemPlacer" is the id of your table.
Try it this way:

```
function addNewItem(){
    jQuery("#itemPlacer tbody").append('<tr><th colspan="2"><label>Track '+currCount+'</label></th></tr><tr><td colspan="1"><label for="itemDetailvar1'+currCount+'">Track var1:</label></td></tr>');             
     currCount++;
    return false;
}
```

Even if you did not create a `<tbody>` element in your table, the browsers usually "correct it" and create one for you.

EDIT:
To add them right after your currently clicked row:

```
function addNewItem(element){
    jQuery(element.parentNode.parentNode).after('<tr><th colspan="2"><label>Track '+currCount+'</label></th></tr><tr><td colspan="1"><label for="itemDetailvar1'+currCount+'">Track var1:</label></td></tr>');             
     currCount++;
    return false;
}
```

And you must pass the "element" argument to your function this way:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addNewItem(this); return false;">Add Another Music Item</a>
```

Please note, the items will be added right after the clicked row... if you add more than 1 row, it will be added BEFORE the last row you added (so right after the clicked row). I don't know if that's the behavior you want...

Comment: Is there a way i can force it just to just add to a certain part of the table? it is now appending it self at the end of the table, after all order details and not where the items are? can i make some form of marker to say, append here and no where else?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/after/
In your case I think it should be `$(this.parentNode.parentNode).after('<tr><th colspan="2"><label>Track '+currCount+'</label></th></tr><tr><td colspan="1"><label for="itemDetailvar1'+currCount+'">Track var1:</label></td></tr>')`

Comment: Hi Naomi, thanks again, i am afraid this has not worked?  Before i had the text "Add another item" and then it appeneded the looped table rows to the bottom of the page regardless, i have changed jQuery("#itemPlacer tbody").append to $(this.parentNode.parentNode).after with no success

Comment: My mistake, forgot that you needed to pass `this` to the function... I've edited my answer (I just tested it and it works)

Comment: Hi Naomi, its now doing... item 1 item 2 item 3, as added from original order, however, once using the administration area, it will then go, item 1, item 2, item 3,(Then add 2 items) item 1, 2, 3, 5, 4?

Comment: Yes, it's "normal"... as I said, the new rows will always add themselves right after the clicked row... so the 2nd added row will not go after the 1rst added row but before it. If you want it to add after the 2nd row, we're gonna have to keep the index of the last added row everytime we add one. The thing is, to go further I'd need to know if you intend to have more than 1 "Add Another Music Item" in your table?

Comment: Hi Naomi, all fixed with you help thank you, was me being daft